# Why is there a need to use purge() of java.util.TimerTask?

Tags: java

Timer.cancel(): Cancels the task.

Timer.purge(): Remove all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue.

What would happen when I would not use purge() here? What would happen when the timer's task queue got filled?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing will change as to the actual Timer behaviour unless you have an ungodly number of timers going on. The cancel method does stop the timer running, but the program will still keep a reference to the timer even after its been cancelled, and so the memory it used will still be in use. The purge method allows Java to mark the timer references for garbage collection, allowing the memory they are using to be used for something else.

Most programs will not need to use the purge method, its just there for programs that will use a lot of timers, either many in a short burst, or if a program is going to be running for many days at a time.